# Efficiently communicating between frontend and backend sites without exposing backend

Tags: php, ajax, database, rest, architecture

I'm trying to figure out whether my current approach will lead me into performance issues into the future, before developing further with this design, and whether there are better ways of doing this. I think this makes the most sense if I provide some context on the design first:

**Current Design**

I currently have my environment designed with two separate servers, let's call them frontend and backend.

1. Frontend

   This server is open to the world. Customers access this site to view our product, make purchases, and will soon be able to view their account related information.
2. Backend

   This server is where all information is held in a database.

**Communication**

The only way that the frontend currently needs access to the backend, is when the user authenticates with their license and downloads our product. To do this, the frontend calls a PHP script, which sends a JSON request to the backend server via curl_exec. The response from the backend tells the frontend how to handle that download request (e.g. license invalid).

**Reasoning**

The reason for this design is to avoid exposing the backend details to the user. Client-side, all the user sees is a request being sent to the frontend server. If the frontend server is ever compromised, anyone reading through how the frontend is built has no access to the backend DB, unless they know exactly what parameters to send to the backend API. Even then, it only gives access to a very low subset of information, depending on what the API exposes.

**The Problem**

The only time this cross-server communication happens right now is when a user tries to download our products using their license details. Relatively speaking, the traffic through this API between both servers is relatively low.

My concerns are that I want to build a user "control panel". From here they can log in with their license/account, they can view their active licenses, access details on previous orders they made, etc. This already means all these pieces of information are only available through the backend, so I'll need to expose them through the API - which is fine. The issue here is that every request the user makes through the control panel (even just refreshing the page) will build up a lot of traffic between both servers.

**Questions**

From the experience of developers here, is this communication design scalable? I'm worried I'm building around a bottleneck, which will just result in a slow user interface, since the frontend would end up waiting on a lot of requests it tunnelled through to the backend.

What are your thoughts? Has anyone faced a similar challenge? How did you overcome that challenge? What is the best practice to achieving this kind of requirement? I hope this question doesn't come across as too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love to hear other answers but I will share my thoughts.

First, let's call your servers:

1. Application Server
2. Database Server

It seems that you are worried about creating a bottleneck due to an increase in the amount of database queries.  Since you mentioned that these queries would execute after a page refresh, it's clear that you are not using a cache of any sort.  If you could cache the database queries and invalidate the cache only if the data has changed (i.e. the user's actions cause the data to change, so the cache should be cleared) then you will increase performance drastically.

If anyone gains access to your application server, they will most likely be able to access the database server with the user that you've allowed the application server to use. You should give this user as little permissions as necessary to use the API.  Still, they may be able to access a lot depending on what your API allows and what you have cached on the application server.

Take a look at [Laravel's cache API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache) which allows you to use your cache in place of a database query. If the cache does not exist, the database query would be executed and cached.  Then you would delete necessary cache's based on user actions. You can also asynchronously recache database requests so you don't prevent a response to the client if the data is not needed for that response.

I hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE:**

After discussing with you further, I better understand your dilemma. You are trying to increase the security of your application by requiring all API calls to go through an extra step of being initiated after a POST request.  I agree that this is going to be a bottleneck as the application scales since you won't be able to take advantage of caching and every page request will result in database queries.

What I have done in a similar case is to separate the application server and database server except the database server is literally only a database server without any logic/scripts. PHP, for example, is not even installed on the database server.  Database servers and applications servers are only connected via private networking, so database servers are only accessible via the application server.  A safe user has been set up to use the remote database.

Since my database queries take a lot of time, I cache as much as possible.

Also consider using https://cloudflare.com It is a reverse proxy to the application server which adds another layer between the client (browser) and your application server.  This way, only cloudflare has access to your application server, and only your application server has access to your database server via the safe database user you create.

Comment: firstly thank you for your thoughts. My concern for the bottleneck is not necessarily the DB queries. More so the communication between the application and database servers, over POST requests between a PHP script on both servers. My goal was to not expose DB details to the application server, instead delegating that to a script on the DB server, which the app server sends "tasks" to.

Comment: I have concerns that these POST requests from the app server script to the DB server script will start being held or throttled by the DB server's web server, since it essentially means the app server's IP is sending large volumes of requests to the DB server. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does not yet make sense to me.  Are you concerned with a large volume of POST requests or other types of requests as well?  Caching is not going to help with POST requests, but it sounds to me like you are adding a large volume of GET requests with your control panel feature -- which caching would help a lot with.

Comment: In the design I'm following here the GET requests from the control panel feature are to a PHP script on the application server, though if I want to keep the DB server isolated, this app server PHP Script would then make a POST request to the DB server's PHP script to get or put the information it needs to.

Comment: It's the POST request volume in this design I'm worried about, but perhaps I'm taking the wrong approach in keeping the DB server isolated and accessible only by POST requests from the app server. That's why I think this won't be scalable. I don't think caching is an option for this either.

Comment: I see, so instead of relaying everything, your thoughts are to allow my app server to directly access the DB, but deny any external DB access to other sources? I can open up external access to the DB from my dedicate app server IP only, so I guess that could work. My only concern here is that it opens up my DB to a DB-dump possibility, if the server is compromised someone more than able to script that together. I'll need to do more digging in how I can keep that as secure as possible.

Comment: Have you heard of https://cloudflare.com/ ?  I use it in my case.  It is a reverse proxy to the application server which adds another layer between the client (browser) and your application server.  This way, only cloudflare has access to your application server, and only your application server has access to your database server.  I've also added this to my answer.

Comment: That's a very interesting point actually. That effectively masks the real IP of my frontend web server. I'll need to look into whether permissions can be used to prevent DB dumps or limit rows to a max number, should someone compromise the server and try to write PHP scripts that make the frontend communicate with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

im no expert on database but using [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
would help you a lot, as it is more secure as well as the best part is..

"Bound parameters minimize bandwidth to the server as you need send only the parameters each time, and not the whole query"

Hope it helps!

Comment: Prepared statements are a great concept I need to implement. Thanks for this. Though if I open up direct backend-DB access to the frontend server, I still have a concern that if the frontend is compromised, and the DB creedntials are found, someone could dump the whole DB by making a script on the frontend / editing an existing one. I need to look at how I can lock that down more, to reduce the likelihood of this happening.